# How to detect which div is being dragged

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an inventory div with multiple divs inside it. I need to figure out which slot being dragged, here is my code. When div is dragged I have to set the selected slot to that slot in my inventory class. I can't get it to work.

```
var numOfSlots = 6;

for(var i = 1; i <= numOfSlots; i++){
  $("#slot"+i ).draggable({
      zIndex: UIlayer++
      start: function(){
         var thestring = $(this).attr('id');
         var thenum = thestring.replace(/^\D+/g, '');
         self.setSelectedSlot(thenum);
    }

  $("#slot" + i).data({
      'initLeft': $("#slot" + i).css('left'),
      'initTop': $("#slot" + i).css('top')
  });
}
```

Comment: Please add your code so we can further assist you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not sure I get your requirement fully, but how about

html:

```
<div class="slot" data-id="1">1</div>
<div class="slot" data-id="2">2</div>
```

js:

```
$(".slot" ).draggable();

$(".slot").on("dragstop", function() {
   console.log($(this).data("id")); 
});
```

will log either 1 or 2 to the console depending on which div you drag. [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jorgthuijls/uJmf4/)

Comment: I think this is all he's looking for.

Comment: actually, my code was already working, the problem was I clicked the pause if exception found in the sources on accident. The game was pausing when it catches an exception in JQuery, which I thought was an error in my code. Thanks for the answer anyway

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```
$("#slot"+i ).draggable({
zIndex: UIlayer++,
start: function(event){
    var element = event.target;
     var thestring = $(this).attr('id');
     var thenum = thestring.replace(/^\D+/g, '');
     self.setSelectedSlot(thenum);
}

$("#slot" + i).data({
'initLeft': $("#slot" + i).css('left'),
'initTop': $("#slot" + i).css('top')
});
```

Comment: doesn't seem to work. The debugger showed up like before